# Exponentiation of a vector

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am following Olver's book *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations* to solve the second order ODE: $\hspace{5mm}y''=0 \hspace{5mm} \text{where} \hspace{5mm} y = f(x)$

I have found the generating vectors $X_1 \hspace{3mm} \text{to} X_8$
( Olver uses  **v** to denote  the vectors rather than X ).

In Olver's text, once the commutator table is found, then, through exponentiation, the groups are found.

I need help with exponentiation.

Here is what I have:

**From Olver**

- If $\mathbf{v} = \partial x \text{   then   } \exp(\epsilon \mathbf{v})x = \exp(\epsilon \partial x )x = x + \epsilon $
- If $ \mathbf{v} = x \partial x \text{   then   } \exp(\epsilon x \partial x) = e^\epsilon x $
- If $ \mathbf{v} = a \partial x \text{   where  } a \text{ is any constant, then   } \exp(\epsilon \mathbf{v})x = x + \epsilon a$

My vectors are as follows:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
X_1=xy\partial x+y^2\partial y  \hspace{10mm} &  X_2=y \partial x \hspace{10mm}  &X_3=x^2 \partial x +xy \partial y \hspace{10mm} &X_4=y \partial y  \\
\\
X_5=x \partial y \hspace{10mm} &X_6=\partial y \hspace{10mm} &X_7=x \partial x \hspace{10mm}& X_8=\partial x\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I am able to find the following groups through exponentiation (based on what I am reading in Olver):
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G_8: & f(x + \epsilon) \\
\\
G_7: & f(e^\epsilon x) \\
\\
G_6: & f(x) - \epsilon \\
\\
G_4: & \frac{f(x)}{e^\epsilon}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

**Note** $ G_a = \text{   the group found by exponentiation of  } X_a $

I need to know if the work I have is correct.
I also need to know how to find the other groups.

Please help.

Comment: I had a similar question once, maybe it can help shed some light on this problem for you. It is found here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770230/meaning-of-generators-in-lie-algebra-of-pde